# Постановка запятых в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

> Осина бывает хороша только в иные летние вечера, когда, возвышаясь отдельно среди низкого кустарника, она приходится в упор рдеющим лучам заходящего солнца, блестит и дрожит (6) с корней до верхушки облитая одинаковым желтым багрянцем (7) или когда в ясный ветреный день она вся шумно струится и лепечет на синем небе.

Mожно ли считать, что запятые на месте цифр 6 и 7 стоят потому, что это определение, оторванное от определяемой части другими словами (..."с корней до верхушки")?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441152/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%a2%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...**с корней до верхушки облитая одинаковым желтым багрянцем** ― это обособленный причастный оборот.

Обособление делается по двум причинам, причем каждая из них одинаково важна и требует обязательного обособления:

1) Определяемым словом является местоимение (она).

2) Дистантное расположение оборота (оторванность от определяемого слова).

Это **формальные** признаки для обособления, но можно ещё добавить, что оборот имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение и его **смысловое** выделение важно для автора.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, эти слова здесь не сказываются. Для постановки запятых достаточно того основания, что имеется причастный оборот, расположенный после определяемого слова (она). В него входит обстоятельство образа действия "с корней до верхушки" (как именно облитая?), само по себе не требующее обособления. Но и при ином порядке следования того и другого - даже при отсутствии множества слов, отделяющих здесь причастный оборот, - запятые понадобились бы ввиду того, что определяемое слово - местоимение:

> ... когда, с корней до верхушки облитая одинаковым желтым багрянцем,
>   она...