# Ошибки у Тургенева?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот как это предложение выглядит в Нацкорпусе.

> Она бывает хороша только в иные летние вечера, когда, возвышаясь отдельно среди низкого кустарника, приходится в упор рдеющим лучам заходящего солнца и блестит и дрожит, с корней до верхушки облитая одинаковым желтым багрянцем, ― или, когда, ж ясный ветреный день, она вея шумно струится и лепечет на синем небе, и каждый лист ее, подхваченный стремленьем, как будто хочет сорваться, слететь и умчаться вдаль. [И. С. Тургенев. Свидание (1850)]

Тут есть явные "описки" (*ж ясный ветреный день*, *она вея шумно струится*), а также вызывает сомнение запятая после *или* (*или, когда, в ясный ветреный день, она вся шумно струится и лепечет на синем небе*). Тире, надо понимать, авторское?

Примечание: запятая после *или* встречается и в других источниках, но не во всех.

Comment: Нужно признать, что НКРЯ не является нормативным источником по которому можно проверять тексты. Там представлено собрание текстов, в т. ч. с орфографическими, грамматическими и другими видами ошибками, которые допускают пишущие.

Comment: @Серж В данном случае вопрос в том, допущена ошибка **пишущим** или тем, кто поместил текст в НКРЯ.

Comment: Не думаю, что Тургенев мог допустить такие ошибки. Поэтому я и написал, что по НКРЯ нельзя проверять грамотность текстов. Хотя на сто процентов утверждать трудно. А найти оригинальный текст или близкий к оригинальному - сложно.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, так выглядят ошибки программы оптического распознавания текста. Даже лишняя запятая могла появиться на месте пятнышка или крупинки в бумаге. Во многих сетевых источниках текст при копировании из первого даже не пытались исправить. Окончательно разобраться можно по печатному источнику, но вот пока более или менее нормальный текст (тире есть, запятой после "или" нет):

http://modernlib.net/books/turgenev_ivan_sergeevich/zapiski_ohotnika/read_15/

Comment: Спасибо! А еще хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение о тире.

Comment: Видимо (если не найдётся более близкого основания), можно подвести это тире под такое правило из Розенталя:
Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении:
2) перед словом, которое повторяется в той же части предложения (придаточной или главной) для того, чтобы связать с ним дальнейшую часть высказывания: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144 В нашем случае связываются с главным два придаточных, начинаемых словами когда (- или когда)

Comment: Из другого раздела:
§ 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении; 2. Условия, благоприятствующие постановке тире: 5) обилие запятых, на фоне которых тире выступает как более выразительный знак
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142