# Есть ли противоречие в предложении «В каждой телеге сидело по одному, много по два мужика в тулупах нараспашку» романа «Отцы и дети» И. С. Тургенева

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, литература

В романе И. С. Тургенева «Отцы и Дети» есть такой текст:

> Несколько телег, запряжённых разнузданными лошадьми, шибко катились по
> узкому просёлку. В каждой телеге сидело по одному, много по два мужика
> в тулупах нараспашку.

Как понимать «В каждой телеге сидело по одному, много по два мужика в тулупах нараспашку»?

Слово «много» в данном случае значит:

> Разг. В сочетании с числительными и словами, обозначающими количество,
> время и т. п., означает: не больше, чем.
> *[Малый академический словарь
> под редакцией Евгеньевой]*

Если заменить слово «много» получится:

*«В каждой телеге сидело по одному, не больше чем по два мужика в тулупах нараспашку»*.

Но если в **каждой** телеге сидело по одному, то, как там при этом могло сидеть не больше двух? Значит, в каких-то телегах было по два, а в каких-то по одному. Но если в каждой сидело по одному, то это исключает возможность того, что где-то могло быть по два. Получается, что первая часть предложения противоречит второй части.

---

Есть ли тут противоречие? Правильно ли построено предложение?

---

**Обновление:**

Скорей всего, слово «много» здесь соответствует по смыслу слову «максимум», которое тоже может использоваться в значении «не более чем».

> **максимум**
> *нареч.* самое большее, не больше ◆ *Я был там пять — максимум десять минут.*

Если слово «много» заменить словом «максимум», предложение имеет смысл.

*«В каждой телеге сидело по одному, максимум по два мужика в тулупах нараспашку»*.

В толковом словаре Ожегова:

> **Мно́го**
> 3. *нареч.* Не больше чем (со словами, обозначающими количество).
> *Пройдёт год, м. два*

*«Пройдёт год, много два»* тоже можно заменить *«Пройдёт год, максимум два»*.

---

По ответу Alex_ander'a:
 Исходя из вышесказанно, никаких устаревших грамматических конструкций тут нет, а прямая подстановка слов может сработать в случае подстановки «максимум» вместо «много».

Comment: *«Пройдёт год, много два» тоже можно заменить «Пройдёт год, максимум два».* - стилистически такая замена не проходит. "Максимум" - это жесткая граница, а "много" таковой не является. Говорю ж - самая правильная замена - на "редко". Но она и не нужна, все и так вполне грамотно и понятно.

Comment: И да, а в чем тогда вопрос-то? После всех ваших пополнений и уточнений в комментариях?

Comment: @behemothus По словарю много — это не больше чем. Это тоже граница. Не больше чем под два — максимум два.

Comment: @behemothus _И да, а в чем тогда вопрос-то? После всех ваших пополнений и уточнений в комментариях?_ Вы правы. Вопрос отпал. Я уже разобрался со смыслом. Но вопросы на этом сайте, к сожалению, удалить нельзя, если есть хотя бы один ответ с одной положительной оценкой. Поэтому ничего не могу сделать. Спасибо за участие в обсуждении.

Answer (score 2):

Как и во всяком *переводе* (здесь - на современный русский), может не сработать прямая подстановка слов с сохранением грамматической конструкции, но исходный смысл всегда можно передать средствами конечного языка. Здесь возможны варианты: "по одному, а то и по два", "по одному, а где и по два", "по одному-два мужика" - во всех этих случаях мужиков не более двух и нет излишнего акцента на "на не более".

Comment: _«...нет излишнего акцента на „на не более“»._ Что тогда означает слово «много»?

Comment: _"Как и во всяком переводе (здесь - на современный русский), может не сработать прямая подстановка слов с сохранением грамматической конструкции..."_ И какая тут устаревшая грамматическая конструкция?

Comment: Здесь правильный "перевод": ***по одному, редко - по двое***. Но я не считаю и авторскую конструкцию устаревшей и нуждающейся в каком-то переводе. Меня больше интересует вопрос, почему у автора одушевленные мужики "по два", а не "по двое". Видимо, тут есть какой-то смысл, мне пока недоступный.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Тургенев да - не отличался изяществом стиля, но данная конструкция вполне нормативна даже по современным номам.

> Но если в каждой телеге сидело по одному, то, как там при этом могло
> сидеть не больше двух?

А эта ваша интерпретация не соответствует смыслу.
"Много" как раз и говорит о том, что может сидеть больше одного, то есть в данном случае - двое. Но это редкость, то есть "если два - то это много" в сравнении со "средним по госпиталю".

Comment: Причём тут Толстой?

Comment: @Eagle  Описка, спасибо. Тургенев.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

*Много* у Тургенева здесь употреблено в значении «не больше, чем».

> **МНО́ГО**
>
> Наречие
>
> 1. В большом количестве, достаточное количество кого-чего-н. "М. знает"
> 2. Не больше, чем (со словами, обозначающими количество чего-н.). "Пройдёт год, м. два"

Источник определений: [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-ru/)

А слова *в каждой телеге* относятся ко всей конструкции *по одному, много по два*. То есть, если перевести фразу на современный русский, получим: «В каждой телеге сидело не больше двух мужиков». Никакого противоречия: число *один* действительно не больше числа *два*.

Тургенев как раз отличался изяществом стиля; впрочем, представления об изяществе встречаются самые неожиданные :)

Comment: "Не больше чем" не синонимично много в этом значении. Оно означает, что трех и больше там не было. А много - не предполагает такого.

Comment: *Тургенев как раз отличался изяществом стиля* - Как я понимаю, это в мой огород камешек. Так вот, если вы хотите поспорить на эту тему, делайте это в комментариях. В самом ответе ваше утверждение выглядит вырванным из контекста.  Но я отвечу. Никак не могу отнести к изяществу стиля неоправданные длинноты (фразы на полстраницы) и частое использование напыщенных слов в прозаическом тексте. Но я написал, что в данном случае к стилю претензий нет

Comment: (+) вот вам, чтоб далеко не ходить, образчик этого "изящного" стиля: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441152 Опечатки пропускаем, саму фразу можно понять без напряга? От вычурности эпитетов глаз не устает? У меня подобное ничего кроме раздражения не вызывает.